# Change Banking Information in Apple developer account

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have a Apple developer account in US, for which I have listed a US bank account in Banking Information in iTunes Connect. Now, I want to edit/change  the bank account to an Indian bank.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah I know I should have asked Apple directly but somehow their technical support team was not able to help me and it is urgent so i thought of asking here for someone who has the experience of changing bank accounts in iTunesConnect successfully

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned on [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/19.0.0.11.5.2.5.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.5.0.1):

> To setup a new bank account on iTunes Connect, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Access the Contracts, Tax and Banking module
> 2. Click on either the "Set Up" or “View/Edit” link in the Bank Info column
> 3. Click on the "Add Bank Account" link
> 4. Select your bank country and click "Next"
> 5. Enter the relevant bank code (local clearing or Swift code) or look up your bank, and click "Next"
> 6. Confirm your bank selection and click "Next"
> 7. Enter your bank account information and click "Next"
> 8. Review the confirmation screen, select the check box at the bottom of the screen to certify your information, and click "Save"
> 9. On returning to the bank account selection screen, select your new bank account from the drop down list, and click "Save"

Comment: "We can't process your request" after step 7

Answer (score 3):

You might also find you need to edit this in a different way:

In App Store Connect:

- Agreements -> Paid Applications -> Bank Accounts -> Edit.

There's "Replace with New Account" there.